# Changing ControlRenderingCompatibilityVersion to version 4.0 loses the src attribute on an ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I'm upgrading an application and have changed the compatibility mode to version 4. After doing this, the following code no longer generates the src attribute in the html of an image button.

```
<asp:ImageButton id="LogOnButton" runat="server"
    ImageUrl="~/Images/login.png" OnClick='LogOnButton_Click' AlternateText="Login">
</asp:ImageButton>
<input type="image" name="LogOnButton" id="LogOnButton" alt="Login" />
```

If I change the mode to 3.5 it renders thus:

```
<input type="image" name="LogOnButton" id="LogOnButton"
    src="Images/login.png" alt="Login" border="0" />
```

Has anyone experienced this, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line from web.config:

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
```

Or change the mode to Strict or Transitional.